# PNP-JS-How to check whether a folder is empty

Tags: pnpjs

I have gone through the questions in this forum and most of them address the Issue of how to check whether a folder exists in a Document Library. But, I would like to know how to check whether a folder is empty using PNP-JS

```
pnp.setup({
    sp: {
        fetchClientFactory: () => new NodeFetchClient(creds),
        baseUrl: "",
        spfxcontext: this.context
    }
});

pnp.sp.web.get()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(`Your web title: ${data.Title}`);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a CAML Query to get the items in the folder. Once you do you can check to see of the length of the results array is zero.

```
let query: CamlQuery = {
    ViewXml: "<View></View>",
    FolderServerRelativeUrl: "/sites/<site>/<list>/<folder>"
};

sp.web.lists.getByTitle("<list name>").getItemsByCAMLQuery(query).then((results) => {
    // ...
});
```